# Angular shows bindings when errors occur. Can this be avoided?

Tags: angularjs, exception

It seems that the default behavior of Angular is to show the bindings that exist in html when an exception is thrown and it can't continue. Is there any way to hide them in this case?

I was thinking that ng-cloak might work for this but I'm trying to avoid adding ng-cloak to each element in my app.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then add `ng-cloak` in a large `div` that contains everything you want to hide. You can even cloak the whole `<body>`.

Another common solution is to add an `isReady` variable on your `$scope`. By default, `isReady` will be `false` and you can display your `{{...}}` with a different value. When everything (like your ajax data) is loaded, set the `isReady` to `true`.

For example, (assuming you are injecting $scope to the controller instead of using controller as vm)

in your html markup,

```
<h1>{{isReady?title:'loading'}}</h1>
```

in the controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('$scope', function($scope){
    activate();

    function activate(){
        // your code to get ajax data...
        $scope.title='title to display';
        $scope.isReady=true; // place at the end when everything before runs without error.
    }
});
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks. I'll stick with adding ng-cloak in the ui state root elements for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngBind instead;

```
<div ng-bind="someExpression"></div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you elaborated a bit more on how this solves the problem

Comment: I think pixelbits means that using this type of binding instead of {{}} will add nothing to the actual element content so nothing will be shown before Angular evaluates the expression. In my case this makes a lot of sense but due to project deadlines I can't refactor the whole app so I'll use Blaise's approach and add the ng-cloak directive in the basic states of my app that contain most of the content.